# Date Stamp on data entry

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to date stamp a field but only when another field has had valid data entered.

below is what I have:

```
Private Sub Purchaser_AfterUpdate()
  If Purchaser.Value <> "" Then
     Date_Alloc.Value = Now()
  End If
End Sub
```

However it does not work.  There is no error message; it just doesn't enter the date.

Comment: Are you calling it from `worksheet_change`? Are you taking the `now()` value and converting it to static unless there's another change?

Comment: When you say "It does not work", why?  Do you get any error or anything?

Comment: No error message just doesn't enter the date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Purchaser.Value` is Null, the condition `Purchaser.Value <> ""` will not be True, so nothing is assigned to `Date_Alloc.Value`.

Change the `If` condition so it is True whenever `Purchaser.Value` is Null or contains an empty string (`""`).

```vb
Private Sub Purchaser_AfterUpdate()
  'If Purchaser.Value <> "" Then
  If Len(Me.Purchaser.Value & vbNullString) > 0 Then
     Me.Date_Alloc.Value = Now()
  End If
End Sub
```